# From template<typename... Types> void func(Types...args) { ... } the value of sizeof...(Types) and sizeof(args) can be different?

Tags: templates, variadic-templates, sizeof

```
template <typename... Types>
void func(Types... args) { }
```

From above code, the value of sizeof...(Types) and sizeof...(args) can be different?
I can't find any case that two values are different. What is it's own usage of each case?